# How to connect multiple "highest in this interval" query calls into one query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, query-optimization

Suppose we have (stripped) entities:

```
Message
{
    int MessageID;
    int DeviceID;
    DateTime Timestamp;
    string Value;
};

Device
{
   int DeviceID;
   string name;
   byte Type;
};
```

We've got 10 000 devices, every one sends up to 5 status messages per minute for two years, what goes into DB. Now we would like, for lets say - 500 chosen devices with Type == 254 create real-time report thingy, that lets you choose some period of time, interval (every day, every 2 hours, 5 minutes or 5 seconds) and on each resulting timestamp you'd get last message before this timestamp. I've tried creating this query, but couldn't get past querying one timestamp (moment in time) at a time:

```
DateTime timestamp = // from argument

var query = from message in this.Messages
    .Include(msg => msg.Device)
    where message.Timestamp <= timestamp
    && msg.Device.Type == 254
    group message by message.DeviceID into g
    select (from message in g
        orderby message.Timestamp descending
        select message).FirstOrDefault();
```

What it does: it limits the timestamps to search from (only getting "before" the timestamp) and groups messages by devices, so we'll get only one message per device. Orderby descending and FirstOrDefault - used to get highest one. There is descending index on Timestamp.

What's the problem with just running it in a loop? Well, users would love to query long periods of time with small intervals quickly with fresh data (last day, interval: 1 minute), what means very big number of requerying of the same query with different parameter (timestamp). For limited amount of data it queries tens of times of timestamps per second and I believe that query which would run once with list of timestamps to search for would finish much quicker.

Is there a way to connect multiple runs of this same query, to get much bigger batch of data at a time? I'm using EF5 but I am not afraid to write stored procedures and sql functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to extend the grouping by some kind of "`IntervalID`" in addition to the `DeviceID`. The `IntervalID` would be an integer that numbers the intervals between your period start and end. You would have as input for your query three parameters:

```cs
DateTime periodStart = ...;
DateTime periodEnd = ...;
int interval = ...; // unit = seconds for example, for 5 minutes it's 300, etc.
```

The `IntervalID` for a given message within the evaluation period is a property that is calculated "on the fly" during the query, in .NET it would be:

```cs
IntervalID = Math.Floor((msg.Timestamp - periodStart).TotalSeconds / interval);
```

You most likely can't use this expression directly in a LINQ-to-Entities query because probably the minus operator for two `DateTime` values is not supported. (`Math.Floor` is supported by LINQ-to-Entities.) But you can try to replace this by `EntityFunctions` (or `DbFunctions` with EF >= 6). The whole query could then look like this:

```cs
DateTime periodStart = ...;
DateTime periodEnd = ...;
int interval = ...; // unit = seconds for example, for 5 minutes it's 300, etc.

var query = from message in this.Messages
            where  message.Timestamp >= periodStart
                && message.Timestamp <= periodEnd
                && message.Device.Type == 254
            select new
            {
                Message = message,
                IntervalID = Math.Floor(EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(
                    message.TimeStamp, periodStart) / interval)
            } into messageInInterval
            group messageInInterval by new
            {
                DeviceID = messageInInterval.Message.DeviceID,
                IntervalID = messageInInterval.IntervalID
            } into g
            select (from messageInInterval in g
                    orderby messageInInterval.Message.Timestamp descending
                    select messageInInterval.Message).FirstOrDefault();
```

`query.ToList()` gives a list of messages that contains the last message per device and per interval.

(Just a basic idea, the code is untested.)